# How to enter text in same textfield using KIF

Tags: ios, ui-testing, kif

I am using Kif and trying to create some data using textfield and add-button

If I use this code once:

```
- (void)addTextItem
{
    [tester enterText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test text %@",[self randomStringWithLength:10]] intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"TBP_TFL_WRITE_YOUR_TEXT", nil)];
    [tester waitAndTapTappableViewWithAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"TBP_BTN_ADD_TEXT", nil)];
}
```

it works well. But if I try to use same textfield again, like:

```
- (void)addTextItem
{
    [tester enterText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test text %@",[self randomStringWithLength:10]] intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"TBP_TFL_WRITE_YOUR_TEXT", nil)];
    [tester waitAndTapTappableViewWithAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"TBP_BTN_ADD_TEXT", nil)];
    [tester enterText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test text %@",[self randomStringWithLength:10]] intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"TBP_TFL_WRITE_YOUR_TEXT", nil)];
    [tester waitAndTapTappableViewWithAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"TBP_BTN_ADD_TEXT", nil)];
}
```

I get this error:

> The step timed out after 10.00 seconds: Accessibility element with
>   label "Write your phrase (use # to create tags)" is not tappable. It
>   may be blocked by other views.

(As you understand "Write your phrase (use # to create tags)"  = `TBP_TFL_WRITE_YOUR_TEXT` )

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
[tester enterText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test text %@",[self randomStringWithLength:10]] intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"TBP_TFL_WRITE_YOUR_TEXT", nil)];
```

You want to use

```
[tester clearTextFromAndThenEnterText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test text %@",[self randomStringWithLength:10]] intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"TBP_TFL_WRITE_YOUR_TEXT", nil)];
```

For the purposes of my explanation lets say the first time you enter "first" and the second time you enter "second".

I'm not entirely sure about that error but I do know that the test will fail because if you do not clear the text field first you are adding to the first entry. This means that the textfield will now say "firstsecond". After KIF has put the text into the textfield the second time it will check for "second" but it won't find it because the textfield actually contains "firstsecond" and so it will fail.

Comment: clearText also doesn't  work, somewhy it doesn't clear text and you get same error

Comment: If clearText is not clearing the text I would ask the author of KIF either by submitting an issue at https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF or by posting in the KIF community help at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kif-framework.

That is a very simple command, a staple of KIF, if it is not clearing the textfield something else is going on.

Comment: Another thing I suggest would be to add a delay both before and after the second text entry using

`[tester waitForTimeInterval:20];`

It could be that something is still loading. The number is seconds. Start high for both and if it works reduce until you get the error again. Then pick a number slightly higher for the days that the server/simulator/device are a bit slower.